# "Because of" usage.

Tags: grammar

What is “Because of” used for?

1) It is cold in Arizona **due to** the westward storm coming from Arizona.

Rule 3: The expression ‘because of’ is used to modify entire clauses. Thus, you can use this expression to present reason for an action in the clause.

Sentence 1 above can be corrected by replacing ‘due to’ with ‘because of’. Now ‘because of’ modifies the clause presenting the reason why it is cold in Arizona.

My question:
Isn't "the westward storm coming from Arizona" a phrase and not a clause? There isn't a complete subject+ verb so it's a phrase right?

Also, when is "because of" best used?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can “due to” and “because of ” be used interchangeably?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7385/can-due-to-and-because-of-be-used-interchangeably)

Comment: "Rule 3" of what?  This looks like you've quoted it from something--could you please mark it as a quote and cite your source properly?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing what *modify* means here.

The words *due to* modify *"It is cold in Arizona",* which is an ***entire clause***. If you changed the sentence to

> The cold in Arizona is due to the westward storm,

the words *due to* would modify *the cold*, and thus it would be correct, according to Rule 3 (which some grammarians dispute the validity of; see the possible [duplicate question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7385/can-due-to-and-because-of-be-used-interchangeably) mentioned in the comment above).

Comment: For the benefit of the backbenchers, would you throw some light on *Rule 3* (and *1*, *2*, and other if any)? Thanks.