# "Due to" or "because of"

Tags: word-choice

I've already read a lot about the usage of "due to" and "because of" and it's clear to me when to use "due to" and when to use "because of".

So "due to" is usually linked to the noun, right?

The cancellation was due to the rain

whereas "because of" is usually linked to a verb

Because of the rain they cancelled it

"Due to" can be replaced by "caused by"

Taking all those rules into consideration should the very famous sentence on YouTube:" Your video has been deleted due to copyright restriction" not be grammatically incorrect?

Or a sentence you hear very often on airplanes is:" Due to safety regulations you have to remain seated until the seatbelt sign has been switched off!"
Shouldn't this sentence also be incorrect?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can “due to” and “because of ” be used interchangeably?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7385/can-due-to-and-because-of-be-used-interchangeably)

Comment: If it's clear to you, then why are you asking for clarification?

Comment: Because sometimes you're wrong even when you think things are clear.  As in this instance.

Comment: Your "rule" isn't one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both those sentences are correct. "Safety regulations" and "Copyright restrictions" are both noun phrases, and in each case "due to" is linked to one of them.
"Due to" can just as correctly be linked to a noun phrase as to a noun as they both serve the same grammatical function.