# "Because/because of/owing to/on account of/due to"?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I was doing my homework but I'm stuck on this exercise.
The instructions say: Complete these sentences: (my answers are in brackets)

1. “Don’t be fool; the dog’s dancing was … the extremely hot pavement.” (*due to*)
2. “I came home earlier yesterday … I was too tired.” (*because*)
3. “It can’t be played ... infringements.” (*because of*)
4. "Royal Jelly is used … its natural healing properties". (*because of*)
5. “ … all of this, their freezer would be filled with ice cream and joy for 
   years!” (*because of*)
6. “… the storm, this Easter we won’t have our picnic.” (*because of*)
7. “The damage was … the lack of motor oil.” (*due to*)
8. “Dialects in Italy vary …few kilometres of distance.” (*because of*)
9. “It seems they lost the match … the quarterback’s illness.” (*because 
   of*)
10. “We can’t buy any ticket now … they’re sold out.” (*because*)
11. “I didn’t buy the eggs … you forgot to write it on the list!” (*because*)
12. “I’m not going on holiday… incoming taxes to pay.” (*because of*)
13. “We didn’t go out … the strike.” (*because of*)
14. “If I am still alive that is … him.” (*because of*)
15. “ … the bad weather, they can’t deliver until Monday!” (*because of*)

The options are:
due to/on account of/because of/because/owing to.

I knew that "due to" as an adjective is mainly used after the verb "be" in sentences like "The cancellation of the concert was due to a heavy thunderstorm" whereas the others are prepositional phrases so the same sentence would be "The concert was cancelled owing to/on account of/because of a heavy thunderstorm".

But I'm a bit confused which one should I pick? Am I wrong about their usages?

Comment: Could you check that you copied No 8 correctly.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I have copied it correctly but for me it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Note that "owing to" is a British-ism to my American ears, so what's considered correct could vary based on culture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can “due to” and “because of ” be used interchangeably?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7385/can-due-to-and-because-of-be-used-interchangeably)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the website: [Quick and Dirty Tips](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/because-due-to-since-and-as), some practical advice

> **Wordy Ways to Say “Because”**
>
> First, let’s disparage all the wordy ways to express the meaning “because.” There are quite a few: “due to the fact that,” “owing to the fact that,” “[on account of](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/on-account-of),” and “on the grounds that,” for example. If you use “because” instead of those beasts, you can save up to four words 
>   ...
>
> **The traditional view is that you should use “due to” only as an adjective, usually following the verb “to be”** (1). For example, if you say, “The cancelation was due to rain,” the words “due to” modify “cancelation.” That sentence is a bit formal, but it fits the traditionalist rule.

From *A Practical English Grammar* by A.J. Thomson, A.V. Martinet

> **due to** (preposition) means ‘a result of’:
>   *The accident was due to carelessness*.
>
> **owing to** means ‘because of’:
>   *Owing to his carelessness we had an accident*.
>
> **due to** should be preceded by subject + verb, but English people are careless about this and often begin a sentence with **due to** instead of with **owing to**

*Because of*, *due to*, and *owing to* express the reason for something. They are usually followed by a noun. **On account of** is very formal and can be used interchangeably with *due to* and *owing to*.

In very formal writing, it would seem that sentences No.5, No.6 and No.15 should begin with **owing to** rather than **because of/due to**

Comment: Apart from n°5-6-15 do you agreee with me with the others?

Comment: @LucaFioravanti No 8 bothers me for some reason, but all the others are fine.