# "Due to" vs "because of"

Tags: meaning

"Due to" is used on a very wide scale as "because of" but some colleagues and friends pointed out to me that this is wrong and "due to" should be used "caused by"...my question is that in the best publications and newspapers I see "due to" as "because of"...is it a matter of style or there is a linguistic rule behind it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can “due to” and “because of ” be used interchangeably?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7385/can-due-to-and-because-of-be-used-interchangeably)  But first, see the [AHD usage note](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/due+to) which has the definitive stance on this.

Comment: The relevant linguistic rule here seems to be that, once enough of us have made the same mistake, it no longer counts as a mistake. (Personally, I prefer to avoid mistakes, even when they don't count.)